# Not able to access CSS from the phone storage in Cordova

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to access CSS file from phone storage in Cordova. The simple use case is to use dynamic CSS. Donwload the CSS from the server on a specific interval, store that in phone storage and use that in style.

The path would be statically defined on the HTML page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///storage/emulated/0/MYAPP_FOLDER/stlyefromstorage.css">
```

**CSS Path (Phone Storage):** `file:///storage/emulated/0/MYAPP_FOLDER/stlyefromstorage.css`

I tried with static CSS file content and that path but didn't work that.

Is it possible in Cordova?

**stlyefromstorage.css**

```
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 300%;
}
p {
  color: red;
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 160%;
}
```

**Index.html (Call from Cordova APK)**

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>
        Hello File Storage CSS
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///storage/emulated/0/MYAPP_FOLDER/stlyefromstorage.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after post my question I found the solution as below:

You can [read/write your file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_file_system.htm) from the installed app folder path as below:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/APP_PACKAGE/files/stlyefromstorage.css
```

In addition, We can access as below:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/APP_FOLDER/stlyefromstorage.css
```

Note: To ensure you have to set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your Androidmanifest.xml -  tag for Android 10+ OS.

Now my external CSS file is working as below:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/APP_PACKAGE/files/stlyefromstorage.css"  />
```

Hope this will helps to others.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to link html & css with a mobile device is to use inline css .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).